# FPDF && BARCODE

Tags: php, barcode, fpdf

I have a little problem, I use a library pi_barcode.php for the generation of the bar code, and fpdf to be able to exploit the barcode and print it, however, I have a problem with the library pi_barcode.php, c 'Is that if I put my file at the root of the server it works but the recording of the image is done at the root, but if my file is put in a folder, then the it wants more to save it but He shows it to me all the same. So basically what I want is to be able to save the image generate barcode in a specific folder and not at the root of the server.

_cb.php :

```
require('pi_barcode.php');

     $code = $_GET['c'] ;

// ***** Création de l'objet
        $objCode = new pi_barcode();

        // ***** Hauteur, [Largeur]
        $objCode->setSize(25);

        // ***** Autres arguments
        $objCode->setText('');
        $objCode->hideCodeType();


        $objCode -> setType('C39');
        $objCode -> setCode($code);
        //Affichage //
        $objCode -> showBarcodeImage();
        //Enregistrement//
        $objCode->writeBarcodeFile($code . '.png');
```

The above code saves the image to the root of the server and if the file is only at the root of the server.

If the file _cb.php is in a folder then the registration is no longer done, and only the display.

Here is the code, pi_barcode.php

```
/* Show image */

function showBarcodeImage()
        {
            $this->checkCode();
            $this->encode();

            if ($this->FILETYPE == 'GIF')
            {
                Header( "Content-type: image/gif");
                imagegif($this->IH);
            }
            elseif ($this->FILETYPE == 'JPG')
            {
                Header( "Content-type: image/jpeg");
                imagejpeg($this->IH);
            }
            else
            {
                Header( "Content-type: image/png");
                imagepng($this->IH);
            }
        }

        /**
        * Save Image
        */
        function writeBarcodeFile($file)
        {
            $this->checkCode();
            $this->encode();

            if ($this->FILETYPE == 'GIF')     imagegif($this->IH, $file);
            elseif ($this->FILETYPE == 'JPG') imagejpeg($this->IH, $file);
            else                              imagepng($this->IH, $file);
        }
```

The code below are the functions called for displaying and saving the bar code

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You should write the full path into

```
$objCode->writeBarcodeFile($code . '.png');
```

like

```
$path     = '/myfolder/';
$filename = 'picture';
$objCode->writeBarcodeFile($path.filename. '.png');
```

Comment: I made the changes, and no changes

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. What is your currently used Path to save the File?